# SQL Query without using sub queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using 2 tables

Let's say (There's more to these tables but that's just a very simple view of it)

```
Table1 is
sID   ResearchPaperID 
1     A1
2     A1
3     A1
4     A1


Table2 is
sID    Name
1     Person1
2     Person2
3     Person3
4     Person4
```

What I need to do is find people who are associated with(co-wrote) Person1's papers but not show Person1 in the output.

Currently I have something like

```
SELECT Table2.sID, Table1.sID
FROM Table2, Table1
WHERE Table2.sID = Table1.sID
AND Table2.Name = 'Person1'
```

which would give me everything that Person1 has done.

This is a homework question been stuck on it for a while now.

**Can't use sub-queries as well. 
Sorry I should mention no use of inner joins, outer joins, left/right joins, natural joins.**

It's not supposed to be much harder than what I have above just using basic commands..

[EDIT]
Output would be something like this

```
ResearchPaperID    Name
A1                 Person2
A1                 Person3
A1                 Person4
```

I want to find people that are co-writers of papers of person1 but not show person1 in the output

Comment: How can you tell that a person co wrote a paper with another person?

Comment: Table1's sIDs show that multiple people wrote the same Research Paper

Comment: Updated the post to show output

Comment: And which SQL? (SQL Server, MySQL)

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.. so whichever one that's using =/ sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: Doesn't my answer gives you what you need?

Comment: I think it does, I'm just having a bit of trouble translating it over to my tables as you've added a third table that represents table1

Comment: @bigubosu . . . Hint:  the final query will probably have a GROUP BY and HAVING clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, without subqueries and JOIN's:

```
select distinct t3.sID, t3.ResearchPaperID
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table1 t3
where t1.sID = t2.sID and t2.Name = 'Person1'
  and t1.ResearchPaperID = t3.ResearchPaperID
  and t3.sID <> t2.sID       -- this restriction is the one that removes the 'Person1'
```

Comment: Is <> is the same as !=? Don't quite understand the t1.ResearchPaperID = t3.ReasearchPaperID.. aren't they just the same tables?

Comment: Yes, `<>` is equal to `!=`. Regarding the two tables, they are the same table yes. But `t1` is restricted with the `sID` of `t2`, so only have the row with `1 A1`. We needed another `Table1` (the `t3`) to select all rows that had the same `ResearchPaperID` but different `sID`. Exactly what you were requesting.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You even went one step ahead and removed duplicates :). Gotta keep that in mind about creating that 3rd table

Comment: @bigubosu and I could also do a `order by t3.ResearchPaperID` :)

Comment: lol, no need question doesn't say I have to. Thanks again, off to practice.

Comment: This is awful.  The answer to a homework assignment should use proper join syntax!

Comment: @GordonLinoff that proper join syntax is not allowed, as stated by OP in other answer comments.

Comment: @aF. . . . In that case, the instructor should be fired ;)

Comment: Not exactly. For instance, in Sybase these types of join are the default ones. The `inner join` (etc.) syntax is ANSI compliant but not the default ^^ It may be the same case for Oracle..

Comment: Technically you're using inner joins... which means I really don't understand the question.

Comment: Just can't explicitly use them

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.ResearchPaperID = t2.ResearchPaperID
INNER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t1.SID = t2.SID
WHERE t3.Name = 'Person1'
```

Comment: Sorry, no Inner Joins or outer joins, natural joins etc. YOu can use where something = somethingelse

Answer (score 1):

You will need to figure out how to identify the *main* author of the paper, and then make the assumption that everyone else is a co-writer.  Once you can do that, your SQL query will need to exclude that main writer but include all the others.

Comment: Sorry, but the definition of the homework tag is: `This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer`